# SQL to find maximum value and then make a decision, which name has the greatest value

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to find "which instructor is taking the maximum number of courses during Fall 2017".

I know I have to use the max function in it, Also I have to count and compare which instructor has the maximum value. but I don't know how to. I have written some part of the query which is

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname
FROM Faculty F 
INNER JOIN CourseSection C ON F.FacID = C.FacID
```

The data of `Faculty` table is

[image]

And `CourseSection` table is

[image]

Comment: What if you have a name conflict, i.e. same combination of firstname and lastname occurs twice?

Comment: I can use FacID for that, but the data which I have has distinct first and last name. So, I can use that here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 F.firstname, F.lastname
FROM Faculty F 
JOIN (
    SELECT FACID, COUNT(*) CNT FROM CourseSection GROUP BY FACID
) C
ON F.FacID = C.FacID
ORDER BY C.CNT DESC
```

Comment: @Sami, sure you can ... you have 22 reps ... means you have upvote privilege. Thus show your appreciation to others for their effort and upvote all the answers if you find them helpful

Comment: @Sami, to expand on what Rahul said, you can upvote multiple answers, but you can only mark one as the accepted answer. You should upvote any answers you found helpful, but mark your final solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try something like this?

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 F.firstname, F.lastname
FROM Faculty F 
JOIN (
    SELECT FACID, COUNT(*) CNT FROM CourseSection GROUP BY FACID
) C
ON F.FacID = C.FacID
ORDER BY C.CNT DESC
```

**MySql:**

```
SELECT F.firstname, F.lastname
FROM Faculty F 
JOIN (
    SELECT FACID, COUNT(*) CNT FROM CourseSection GROUP BY FACID
) C
ON F.FacID = C.FacID
ORDER BY C.CNT DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**ALLOW TIES**

This is a SQL Server code (using a Common Table Expression) to allow selection of multiple instructors in case of ties:

```
; with t as (
select FacID, COUNT(*) CNT
from CourseSection
group by FacID
    )
select F.FirstName, F.LastName, t.CNT from t join Faculty F on F.FacID = t.FacID
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from t)
;
```

Comment: @Rahul thanks, still I have a [working demo](http://rextester.com/XUKZ5613) here, can you explain why this seems to work?

Comment: Is this definitely MySQL?

Comment: looks like sql server based on screenshots

Comment: @Rahul "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'."

Comment: So, is it sql-server?

Comment: adjusted answer -- removed LIMIT 1 and inserted TOP 1

Comment: @Sami, you are using `SQL Server` and tagged your question as `MySQL` ... what a waste!!!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis yes it is.

Comment: @Rahul adjusted OPs tags by changing mysql to sql-server

Comment: Next time, please accept an edit so those who contribute can get the assist when the answer is accepted :)

Comment: Downside of this answer is that if you have a tie for 1st place, you only get one. Does that matter? Do you want both/all in such cases?

Comment: @user1327961 Sure :)

Comment: @SteveLovell if there's a tie, then it must show both.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, I would have not edited the answer if I were you ... don't care much when OP doesn't show sincerity / seriousness. BTW, nice work...appreciate you have included both version.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP` and take the `TOP 1` to get the max.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Faculty
WHERE FacID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 FacID
    FROM CourseSection
    GROUP BY FacID
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC )
```

The subquery in the `WHERE` clause will get the `FacID` of the faculty member who took the most courses.

```
SELECT TOP 1 FacID     --Take just the top 1 record as that is the max
FROM CourseSection
GROUP BY FacID         --Group by the FacID to get a count of courses per FacID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC --Order by the number of courses descending so the max is at the top
```

Since this subquery will return a single record it can be used in a comparison statement, so we simply put it in the the `WHERE` clause.

This will throw an exception though if the CourseSection table is empty and the subquery returns no results. You could prevent this by instead using an `IN` statement, even if it is less expressive.

```
WHERE FacID IN ( ... )
```

Comment: This solution will also only give you one faculty member even if there is a tie. I've added my own answer which resolves that.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested this, so I may have made a typo somewhere, but the following logic should be right, and will give all the Faculty members involved in any tie.

```
select
    F.FacID, 
    F.FirstName,
    F.Lastname 
from
    Faculty F
    JOIN (
         select top 1 count(1) as MaxClasses
         from  CourseSection cs1
         group by cs1.FacID
         order by count(1) desc) as MaxClasses
    JOIN CourseSection cs2 ON
         F.FacID = cs2.FacID
group by
    F.FacID, 
    F.FirstName,
    F.Lastname
having
    count(1) = MaxClasses.MaxClasses
```